# How to make record insert operation faster in django with postgres backend

Tags: django, performance, postgresql

I build a django based geolocation service which determines user's location by their IP address. The first thing I need to do is to insert ip data into my database.

I used following code(simplified) to insert records into my db:

```
 for ipLoc in ipSeeker.ipLocationList:
     placeName =ipLoc.country + ipLoc.area
     IPLog.objects.create(
                startIP = int_to_dqn(ipLoc.startIP), 
                endIP = int_to_dqn(ipLoc.endIP), 
                place = placeName
     ).save()
```

The ipLocationList has approx 400k ip records. And my script only insert 20k records in 20 minutes. It is tooooooo slow and could not be accepted.

So my question is: where is the bottleneck and how could I make it faster?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See my answer on this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019831/bulk-batch-update-upsert-in-postgresql/7020219#7020219.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use raw sql and transactions for django-side: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/ along with the Copy command from Postgres!

[Whats the fastest way to do a bulk insert into Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758945/whats-the-fastest-way-to-do-a-bulk-insert-into-postgres)

Answer (score 1):

I found a complete tutorial about how to load GEOIP database into postgresSQL in the siafoo. It is well written and covers most detail. 
The link is http://www.siafoo.net/article/53