# Hibernate + enabling SQLite Pragmas to gain speed on Windows 7 machine

Tags: java, hibernate, sqlite, windows-7, pragma

Used software:

- hibernate 3.6
- sqlite jbdc 3.6.0
- java jre 1.6.X

I have a problem with transferring data over a tcp connection ( 20 000 entrys )

- create a sqlite database with the help of hibernate
- use hibernateview and hibernate annotations to create querys
- hibernate proberties are also used
- storing 20 000 entries with hibernate and NO sqlite pragmas enabled lasts nearly 6 minutes ( ~ 330 sec) on Windows 7
- storing 20 000 entries without hibernate and all relevant sql pragmas enabled lasts ca 2 minutes ( ~ 109 sec ) on windows 7
- tests with hibernate and sqlite without pragmas on windows XP and windows Vista run fast, but on win7 it lasts nearly
  3 times ( ~ 330 sec - win 7) as long as on the XP machine
- on windows 7 we want to activate sqlite pragmas to gain speed boost
- relevant pragmas are:

  ```
  PRAGMA cache_size = 400000;
  PRAGMA synchronous = OFF;
  PRAGMA count_changes = OFF;
  PRAGMA temp_store = MEMORY;
  PRAGMA auto_vacuum = NONE;
  ```

**Problem:** we must use hibernate ( no Nhibernate ! )

Questions:

- how to enable these pragmas in hibernate sqlite connection if its possible?
- Is it possible to do so with using hibernate?

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking for some way to set another pragma: **PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON** for hibernate connections. I didn't find anything on the subject and the only solution I came up with is to decor SQLite JDBC driver and set required pragma each time new connection is retrieved. See sample code below:

```
@Override
public Connection connect(String url, Properties info) throws SQLException {
    final Connection connection = originalDriver.connect(url, info);
    initPragmas(connection);
    return connection;
}

private void initPragmas(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    //Enabling foreign keys
    connection.prepareStatement("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;").execute();
}
```

Full sample is here: https://gist.github.com/52dbc7066787684de634. Then when initializing **hibernate.connection.driver_class** property just set it to your **package.DriverDecorator**

Answer (score 0):

Inserts one-by-one can be very slow; you may want to consider batching.  Please see my answer to [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019831/bulk-batch-update-upsert-in-postgresql/7020219#7020219).

Answer (score 0):

for `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON` equivalent

```
hibernate.connection.foreign_keys=true
```

or

```
<property name="connection.foreign_keys">true</property>
```

depending on your strategy