# Postgresql batch update

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to batch update the following sample more efficiently.

```
users = [{id: 424, pos: 1}, {id: 23, pos: 2}, {id: 55, pos: 3}, ...]

//currently loop updating each {i}:
   UPDATE users SET position = i.pos WHERE id = i.id
```

Comment: Aren't you looking for this ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/20224370/3277024

Comment: @JMG Yes, i take a look. Thx

Answer (score 1):

You can use `unnest()`:

```
update users u
    set position = user.pos 
    from (values ([{id: 424, pos: 1}, {id: 23, pos: 2}, {id: 55, pos: 3}, ...])
         ) v(users) cross join lateral
         unnest(users) user
    where u.id = user.id
```

Comment: This is supposed to help me, let me try

Comment: Could you explain me this `v(users) cross join lateral unnest(users) user`, if my array is named `list = []` for example ? I am kinda getting syntax issue here.

Comment: @7urkm3n . . . https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#Lateral.