# Database schema design optimized for scoring rows to sort on

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design, database-schema

I want a table like this which has scores column, and whenever `basket1` or `basket2` are added to table I want to update scores of the columns in basket.So say `basket1 =[potato, tomato, orange]` and `basket2 = [potato, apple, orange]` are inserted in db, I want to subtract 1 from items in baskets and increment the score for basket.

So if I have a table like this and when I insert 5,6 I want to do the math operation

```
prod_id  name      score
---------------------------
1       potato     10 (-1, -1)
2       tomato     10 (-1)   
3.      orange     10 (-1, -1)  
4.      apple.     10  (-1)
5.      basket1.   40  (+3)
6.      basket2    40  (+3)
```

Obviously I can look at basket 1 array and do N number of db queries to update rows, because say if there are 1000 items in basket, will DB become slower/locked if we are updating so many rows in 1 query, but I am trying to figure out if there is any optimized way where I can do this with minimal impact on read queries performance. Alternatives I thought were maybe create another table for scores and keep track of scores there. Are there any other way where I can intelligently layout the db schema such that performance impact is bare minimum

Comment: Is there a requirement regarding db-transactions? I.e. has one basket to be processed in one db-transaction? Or has only one item to be processed in one db-transaction?

Comment: @Markus 1 db-traction per basket would be good, but its still ok to one item per db-transaction if its simpler/faster query responses..less contention/locking

Comment: And what are the requirements for performance? Will the basket processing be some kind of batch where performance is not that critical? Where does the basket information with such many items per basket come from? From the database, from a file or from interactive user interface?

Comment: @Markus while creating baskets it’s not critical but all other select queries  performance is critical. Basket creation happens from api

Comment: What is the business logic for the score?  Is it to maintain inventory?  Or total number of items?  What is the requirement behind this score, that you want to use to sort?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any issue with your current data model. Keep it smart and simple. Writing data to Postgresql will never lock reading because of its [multiversion concurrency control feature](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.1/mvcc.html).

Also 1000 or 2000 updated rows per transaction shouldn't be any issue, too. However, if write performance is no issue I would recommend that you use as less concurrent workers for writing as possible, at best only one. This will help that the writing jobs don’t block each other.

From a functional point of view I wouldn't call the id “prod id“ because baskets are no products. The table contains scores, so better call it scores. But of cause I don't know the rest of the data model.

General rules:

- always plan your indexes and queries thoroughly
- if you have concurrent writers and you write to multiple tables in one transaction then do it always in the same order to avoid deadlocks
- if you have concurrent writers and if you update multiple rows of the same table in one transaction then always do it in the same order, best by increasing primary key, to avoid deadlocks
- use bulk update features of the DB framework of your choice ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019831/bulk-batch-update-upsert-in-postgresql))