# Inserting 1million tuples in DB taking long time

Tags: java, mysql

I have an scenario where i need to insert 1million entries using sql. Which is taking long time.
I have Database structure with 9 tables, in every operation i need perform below tasks.

```
1. Open Connection
2. Insert tuples in 9 tables with maintaining Primary/foreign key relationship
3. Commit
4. close the connection
```

Repeat the operation for 1million time.

i am inserting 800 iterations/hour.
Which i feel too slow, 
Do you have any better ways to improve on this?

Comment: Yeah. Don't close the connection.

Comment: Will not lead to inconsistance?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: You mean to say open connection only once and close only after all the insertions right?

Comment: Yes, that's what I said.

Answer (score 1):

Try inserting by **Batch** (i.e. PreparedStatement). Maybe you are inserting them individually.

e.g.

```
for(int i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
   // set parameter 1 to rows[i][0]
   preparedStatement.setObject(1, rows[i][0]);
   // set parameter 2 to rows[i][1]
       .
       .
       .
   preparedStatement.addBatch();
   // insert 10k rows
   if(i % 10000 == 0)
       preparedStatement.executeBatch();
}
preparedStatement.executeBatch();
```

In this case where you have foreign keys, batch insert first the data to tables without FKs.

[Why are batch inserts/updates faster? How do batch updates work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006969/why-are-batch-inserts-updates-faster-how-do-batch-updates-work)

Answer (score 0):

Try to run execute the query in bulk as suggested in above answers. make sure to take care of rollback strategy in case error is thrown for a particular data.

Different strategies if error is thrown by a batch are : 
1. full rollback 
2. Commit at logical point and rest rollback.